# how to make copies of bunch of files but keep continuing sequential numbers

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files named

```
slice0001.bmp, ..slice0128.bmp
```

I need to make 3 more copies of each with `slice0129.bmp` should be a copy of `slice0001.bmp` and so on. How to do it using bash?

I could do adding using `$(($i + 128))` but with padding, it was getting difficult.

Comment: please update the question with your complete set of code (eg, how did you obtain `$i`?)

Comment: Would `((n = i + 128))` `newnum=$(printf "%04d" $n)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the numeric range, and add the appropriate increments for each copy. Use `printf` to add the leading zeros.

```
for i in {1..128}; do
    for inc in 128 256 384; do
        cp "slice$(printf '%04d' $i).bmp" "slice$(printf '%04d' $((i+inc))).bmp"
    done
done
```

Comment: Elegant solution !! Thanks Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Using `Perl`:

#### Input files

```
$ ls -1
slice0001.bmp
slice0002.bmp
slice0003.bmp
```

#### Code

```
plus=128
printf '%s\n' slice0*.bmp |
    perl -slne '
        my $file=$_;
        s/slice(\d+)/sprintf "slice%.6d", ($1 + $plus)/e;
        system("cp $file $_")
    ' -- -plus=$plus
```

#### Result

```
$ ls -1tr
slice0001.bmp
slice0002.bmp
slice0003.bmp
slice000129.bmp
slice000130.bmp
slice000131.bmp
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles. This might work, but looks bit complex to be as I'm not good at perl.